# Variables scope in python

Tags: python, variables, scope

My question might be simple but I really cannot figure out where I went wrong.
I would like to pass one variable from a function to another function. I use return therefore but I'm always getting an error message, that my variable is not defined.

My code is:

```
url = "http://www.419scam.org/emails/2004-01/30/001378.7.htm"

def FirstStrike(url):
    ...
    return tokens

def analyze(tokens):
    ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    FirstStrike(url)
    analyze(tokens)
```

If I run this I got an error message: NameError: name 'tokens' is not defined.

Comment: A `return` statement returns an object, not a name or a "variable".

Comment: Rather than making people read your whole source file, a backtrace would have made answering much easier. So would minimizing the code to the smallest bit that fails in a way you don't understand. I have chopped out all but the relevant bits of your code sample, if you did the same, your problem might have been more obvious to you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you run the code, you haven't assigned the result of `FirstStrike` to a variable:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    tokens = FirstStrike(url)
    analyze(tokens)
```

This is necessary because otherwise `tokens` is not defined when you call `analyze`.

Answer (score 4):

```
tokens = FirstStrike(url)
```

You must assign FirstStrike return value to tokens variable before calling analyze(tokens)